# Show $\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + ... + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n \space \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients

I was requested to show

$$\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + ... + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n \space \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

Since I self study, I have no professor to tell me whether my solution is correct or not. I wonder if anyone could provide some validation. Here is what I did.

$I$. Let $n=1$ and the equality trivially holds.

$II.$ Let our inductive hypothesis $\text{HI}$ be that

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} = 2^k$$

Then we want to show

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{i} = 2^{k+1}$$

$III.$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{i} 
&= \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k+1}{i} + \binom{k+1}{k+1}
\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k \Big(\binom{k}{i-1}+\binom{k}{i}\Big) + 1 
&&\text{By Pascal's triangle formula}
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i} + \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} + 1
\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i} - \binom{k}{0} + 2^k+1 
&&\text{HI}
\\
&=2^k-1+2^k+1
\\
&=2^{k+1}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$

and thus we have proved what we set out to show.

The two questions I always have when finishing a proof: Is the proof correct? Are there alternative, perhaps simpler proofs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is ok, writing the solution may look different (to have a better feeling of symmetry of the split), but the idea inside it is the same. Usually, one "knows" the binomial formula$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{0\le k\le n}\binom nk a^kb^{n-k}\ ,$$and applies it for $a=b=1$. But then, e.g. in an exam the next question is to show this binomial formula.... and this happens either by combinatorial means (try to count the coefficient of any of the terms after removing parentheses), or by induction, and then we have the above in a slightly more general setting.

Comment: There are many proofs. One is a "combinatorial", or proof by bijection. If you have a set of $n$ elements, the right side is counting the number of subsets of that set, where each factor $2$ is counting the number of ways of having a particular element or not in the set (two ways). The left is counting the same, since $\binom{n}{k}$ is counting how many subsets of $k$ elements there are.

Comment: Your method is equivalent to observing that in Pascal's triangle each of the digits in row $n$ is used twice in obtaining row $n+1$. There is a neat trick for doing this quickly using the binomial expansion which @dan_fulea has explained. If you look at the questions on the binomial coefficients tag you will find some other interesting tricks and identities. For a combinatorial proof (two ways of counting the same thing) you can do it by choosing a selection from $n+1$ objects by choosing some of the first $n$ and then deciding whether the extra object is in or out of the set.

Comment: In the second line of $III$ you are doing a k choose $i-1$ but you are allowing $i$ to be $0$. You mean to say that you treat it as $0$ in that case, but your notation does not reflect that.

Comment: Alternative approach is to consider (for example) $(1 + 1)^n$, applying the binomial theorem.  That is, $$(a + b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n a^i b^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}.$$  Then, you simply set $a = 1 = b.$

Comment: All these comments were so, so helpful. Thank you so much to everybody, I didn't expect such a rich set of answers to come out of this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the step $$\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i-1} = \sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i}$$ is justified, although it ends up being true. If you do replace i-1 with i, you should get $$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i-1} \\
&= \sum_{i=-1}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i} \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\right) - \binom{k}{k} \\
&= 2^k - 1
\end{align*}
$$

Also, as the comment mentions, you can do
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} 1^{n-k}1^k \\
&= (1+1)^k = 2^k
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I think that step simply uses $\binom {k}{-1} =0$ - the top limit is not changed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the first part: there is a slight error between lines 2 and 3 in III part. If you change summation variables via $i \rightarrow i + 1$ the  summation should begin at $i = 0$ and end at $i = k - 1$, not at $i = k$.
Thus it should be
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^k \left( {k \choose i - 1} + {k \choose i} \right) +1 =
\sum_{i = 0}^{k-1}  {k \choose i - 1} +1+\sum_{i = 0}^k{k \choose i}
$$
$$
=\sum_{i = 0}^{k-1}  {k \choose i - 1} +{k \choose k}+\sum_{i = 0}^k{k \choose i}= 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k +1}.
$$

I assumed that ${n \choose -1}= 0$ using definition of a Newton symbol via [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Second part: there is a combinatorial interpretation which in this case gives simpler proof. Suppose we have a set of $S$ consisting of $n$ elements and you want to count the number of subsets of $S$.
You can do it in two ways:

- Count subsets consisting of $i$ elements, where $i = 0, 1, \dots, n$.
  For example there is only one set with zero elements - empty set, ${n \choose 1}$ subsets consisting of exactly one element and so forth.
  Total number of subsets is
  $$
  \sum_{i = 0}^n {n \choose i}.
  $$
- For each element $s \in S$ decide if the subset $X \subset S$ contains $s$ or not. For each element you have exactly two choices, so the total number of
  different subsets is $2^n$.

Since we counted the same thing in two different ways we obtain that $2^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n {n \choose i}$.

Answer (score 1):

If in the binomial formula

$$\big(a+b\big)^n=\sum_\limits{k=0}^n\binom nk a^k b^{n-k}$$

we let $\,a=b=1\,,\;$ we get that

$$2^n=\sum_\limits{k=0}^n\binom nk$$

that is

$$\binom n0+\binom n1+\binom n2+\ldots+\binom nn=2^n$$